# logs Challenge between two students >>be smart

Tags: logarithms

two student were given the equation  $2^{4x+6} = 3^{6x-3}$

1.steve rearranged to get  $2^{4x+6} - 3^{6x-3} =0$

then wrote $\log (2^{4x+6} - 3^{6x-3}) = \log0$

are these legal steps ? if not explain what is wrong with them

2 Ali wrote $\log( 2^{4x+6}) =\log(3^{6x-3})$  then $\log( 2^{4x+6}) - \log(3^{6x-3})=0  $

finally $2^{4x+6} / 3^{6x-3}$

are these legal steps ? if not explain what is wrong with them

Comment: Hint. What's $\log 0$?

Comment: Please don't dump questions here without giving a source, a reason to be interested, some evidence that you have actually thought about the problem, and so on.

Comment: log 0 = 1 this is the answer

Comment: @MomenOsama Are you sure? Why do you say that? What's $10^0$?

Comment: 10^0 = 1  i am sure

Comment: @MomenOsama, if $10^0=1$ then $\log_{10}1=0$, not $\log_{10}0=1$.

Comment: I have a feeling that was supposed to be $2^{4x+6}$, not $2^{4x}+6$, and so on --- but, who knows?

Comment: the edit of question is wrong

Comment: yes Gerry Myerson  thats corrects

Comment: there is a problem in the editing

Comment: yes now the editing is correct  thanks vadim123

Comment: If you are not going to use $\LaTeX$, please use parentheses to show what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is not legal as you cannot take the log of $0$.  The second is legal, but I do not see it as progress toward finding $x$.  Ali should use the laws of logarithms to pull down the powers.  His finally can be reached in one step from the initial equation and does not give a value for $x$.

Comment: thanks  Ross Millikan    <<< so ali and steve are not correct

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite you equation as 
$$
\bigg(\frac{2^2}{3^3}\bigg)^{2x}=3^{-3}2^{-6}
$$

Can you handle from here?

Answer (score 0):

The first task is to get the unknown out of the exponents.

Do not rearrange the equation. Rather, make the substitutions:$$3=e^{\ln (3)}$$ $$2=e^{\ln (2)}$$which yields $$e^{(\ln2)\times (4x+6)} = e^{(\ln 3) \times (6x-3)}$$ Yoe now have two exponential terms, with the same base, equal to each other.  The exponents must then be equal. You are left with a simple linear equation with one unknown. (Two of the coefficients are sort of ugly!)